# How to implement custom exceptions for guessing game

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, multi-catch

I have to create a guessing game that allows for up to 5 turns and the user input must be between 1 & 10 inclusive. If these criteria aren't met, then two custom exceptions may be thrown (BadGuessException & TooManyGuessesException). I'm stuck on how to do my exception handling because I'm not sure how to make the program know whether or not to throw and catch these custom exceptions.

I created two classes for the custom exceptions:

```
public class BadGuessException extends Exception
{
  /**
   * no-arg constructor
   */
  public BadGuessException()
  {
    super("Sorry, that was an invalid guess!");
  }

  /**
   * parametrized constructor
   * @param message String message passed to super class's constructor
   */
  public BadGuessException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}

public class TooManyGuessesException extends Exception
{
  /**
   * no-arg constructor
   */
  public TooManyGuessesException()
  {
    super("Sorry, too many guesses!");
  }

  /**
   * parametrized constructor
   * @param guess integer value representing amount of guesses (turns)
   */
  public TooManyGuessesException(int guess)
  {
    super("Sorry, you guessed " + guess + " times!");
  }

}
```

And in the following code I'm trying to allow for up to five turns before a TooManyGuessesException is thrown, and I'm trying to handle an exception for a number input less than 1 and greater than 10. I'm required to have only one try-catch block (and the extra catch clause for NumberFormatException).

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Scanner object to receive user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Create Random class object & random variable
    Random rng = new Random();
    int n = rng.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;

    //Create incrementor for guessing turns
    int turn = 1;
    //Create variable for user input (guess)
    int guess;


    try
    {
      while(guess != n && turn <= 5)
      System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10 inclusive.");
      System.out.println("Hint: the answer is " + n);
      guess = keyboard.nextInt();
      turn++;
      if(guess == n)
      {
        System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nIt took you " + turn + " attempts.");
      }

    }
    catch(BadGuessException e | TooManyGuessesException e)
    {
      if(guess < 1 || guess > 10)
        e.BadGuessException();
      if(turn > 5)
        e.TooManyGuessesException();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry, you entered an invalid number format.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Oracle's tutorial on exception handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) covers the basic syntax and control structures quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Check first that the input number fills the criteria before comparing it to the answer:

```
if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
    throw new BadGuessException();
} else if (guess == n) {
    System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nIt took you " + turn + " attempts.");
}
```

As for the `TooManyGuessesException`, it will never be thrown since you limit your `while` loop to end after a certain number of iterations. remove `turn` from the loop condition and use it in an `if` statement that checks if turns are too many.

Answer (score 1):

What @Jack Flamp just said is totally correct, but you don't want to check if the guess is between 1 and 10 inclusive, but if the user guess match with your random number.

```
if (guess == n) {
    System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nIt took you " + turn + " attempts.");
} else {
    throw new BadGuessException();
}
```

If you want an exception to be thrown when the turn variable exceed 5, delete it from the while condition and make a if at the start of the while scope:

```
if (turn > 5)
    throw new TooManyGuessesException();
```

PS : Put brackets around your while scope, else you will have a TooManyGuessesException instantly

PS2 : I wanted to comment the Jack Flamp message, but since I don't have 50 in reputation, I can't.